# How can I assign a material to a gameobject when selecting it and change it back to the original material when deselecting the gameobject using C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have multiple gameobjects in the scene with different materials on it. When i select a gameobject its material must change to selectMat. My code works in the editor, and on my samsung s8 it also works but after a number of times selecting different gameobjects the selectedMat material stays on the gameobject and it won't change back to the originalMat.

I realy can use some help with this.

```
{
public GameObject SelectedObject;
public Material SelectMat;
public string Path = "StringPath";
private Material originalMat;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    originalMat = Resources.Load<Material>(Path);

}

public void Update()
{

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            GameObject hitObject = hit.transform.gameObject;
            hitObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = originalMat;
            SelectObject(hitObject);
            hitObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = SelectMat;

        }
        else
        {
            ClearSelection();
        }
    }
}
void SelectObject(GameObject obj)
{
    if (SelectedObject != null)
    {
        if (obj == SelectedObject)
        {
            return;
        }
        SelectedObject = obj;
    }
}

void ClearSelection()
{
    if (SelectedObject == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        SelectedObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().sharedMaterial = originalMat;
        SelectedObject = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well you used `sharedMaterial` when clearing selection. But when you select it you used `material` that is causing the issue most likely.

Answer (score 0):

After you change the `material` the `Renderer` uses a local instance of that material. Changing `sharedMaterial` after that afaik doesn't have any effect.

Use

```
SelectedObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = originalMat;
```

instead